# Reverse proxy in home network

Tags: .htaccess, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to set up a reverse proxy in my home network.  The idea is to route traffic to correct port number based on subdomain in the request URL.

Example:  I'm setting two subdomain A records on my domain: `nas.mydomain.tld` and `wiki.mydomain.tld`.  Both A records point to my dedicated IP address at home.  I want a reverse proxy that routes:

- `nas.mydomain.tld` => `192.168.2.2:5001`
- `wiki.mydomain.tld` => `192.168.2.2:8090`

Can this be done in e.g. my ASUS RT-AC55U router, or can I route all traffic to my file server and have a reverse proxy there route the traffic to correct IP addresses and ports?

Comment: Hi, I have also the same problem. Previously I planned to go with a standalone reverse proxy (either containerized in docker or virtualized in proxmox) but now I'm also searching about how to manage a reverse proxy within my router (an Archer C7).. I only know that it is compatible with openwrt. And in fact it might be possible to integrate a reverse proxy in openwrt. I keep following your thread (btw it would be great if any answers come..)

Comment: Yes, I hope some good answers will come eventually.  However, I know a bit more about it now than I did earlier, so I'll write an answer about it.  I'll leave the question unanswered however, to see if someone has a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I found out, the problem lies in that the functionality I want (multiple types of content retrieved from the same IP and port) cannot be done without some kind of middle-man; a reverse proxy server that fetches the content based on the URL and relays it.

**Asus router:** My ASUS RT-AC55U router doesn't have a reverse proxy server, at least not with standard firmware.  I haven't researched if some unofficial kind of firmware contains a reverse proxy server for doing this.  So the only option is to use a NAT record to route port 80 to a specific port.  The downside is that it only supports one web service on the IP address.

**Web hotel:** Creating a rewrite in a .htaccess file on the web hotel of a registrar, but it will only redirect and not rewrite/mask URL.  Otherwise, the registrar would need a reverse-proxy server to fetch the content from the web services to relay it.  I don't think my current registrar supports this, and I can understand if they don't want to do it from a security standpoint.

**Apache reverse proxy server:** Apache supports this using the mod_proxy module and an entry in the conf file.  More info on it here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#proxy

**CCProxy:** CCProxy is definitely the easiest solution that I've found so far.  It's a simple GUI application where you can add URL's, host names/IP addresses and ports, and the application takes care of the rest.  Also has a very nice graphical representation of usage/bandwidth, and a graphical log of ongoing sessions.  More info here: http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/

Comment: Yes, the main purpose is to serve many different *http* based services with one single IP discriminating upon subdomain/domain.  A simple solution like CCProxy is indeed a good way to test an architecture..  But *in my case* I'm not fan of software that is not open source (might be paid, it's not a problem, especially for so little bucks)..  Networking is vital in my opinion..  Keep seearching for a rapid solution while waiting for more learning using eg. nginx or haproxy..